# Use a power supply as a switch

Tags: computers, fan

I have some extra fans to cool my Xbox (4). I think that they would drain too much power if I connected them strait to the internal Xbox fan. So I want to know if I have a power suppliy for the extra fans, how can I get them to turn on when the internal Xbox fan turns on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin said, you could use this circuit to control the extra fans. [image: this]

Comment: Awesome, thank you for clearing that up :) so if the fan on the Xbox is 12v would I just use. 12v relay?

Comment: Yes, the relay coil should have the same voltage rating than the fan.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution to this is a relay. Say the existing fan is 12V d.c. (as per PCs), wire a relay coil across the existing fan connections, in parallel with it, and wire the (normally open) contact pair in series with your power supply and the new fans eg break the +12V line of your new power supply. It is safer for you to do this by breaking the 12V line to the fans than breaking into the mains live terminal to your power supply since it reduces your risk of electrocution and possible damage to your Xbox if a wire comes loose, but it means the new supply is running all the time.

Comment: Don't forget the free wheel diode in parallel with the relay coil (cathode connected to the positive terminal). Without it you may burn the fan control circuit, and make sure the control circuit can handle the current required for the relay and the fan.

Comment: So are you saying Power from the Xbox fan cables gos into the relay then back out the internal fan and from the other terminals on the relay go to the other fans and it acts as a switch, turning on when power gos though it?

Answer (score 0):

I've built an [electronic thermostat](http://www.velleman.eu/products/view/?country=nl&lang=en&id=347925) to cool my 'disk cabinet'. It keeps my disk drawer at a fairly constant temperature of 27 - 28 degrees (air temp). Advantage is that the fan only runs when required; rarely during winter season and every now and then during summer season.